# Distance between two points using the distance formula

Tags: python, wing-ide

So I need to calculate the distance between a current point and another point specified in the parameter & Return the distance calculated

My print statement needs to look something like this:

```
> print p1.distance(p2)   
5.0
```

My current code:

```
import math

class Geometry (object):
    next_id = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = Geometry.next_id
        Geometry.next_id += 1

geo1 = Geometry()
print geo1.id
geo2 = Geometry()
print geo2.id

class Point(Geometry):
    next_id = 0

    def __init__(self,x,y,):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.id = Point.next_id
        Point.next_id += 1  

    def __str__(self):
        return "(%0.2f, %0.2f)" % (self.x, self.y)

    def identify():
        if(p0.id == p1.id):
            print "True"
        else:
            print "False"

    def equality():
        if (self.x == self.y):
            print "True"
        else:
            print "False"  

    def distance(p0, p1):
        p1 = pts1
        pts1 = [(7.35,8.20)]
        p0 = pts0
        pts0 = [(5,5)]
        dist = math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p0[1] - p1[1])**2)
        return dist

p0 = Point(5,5)
print p0.id
p1 = Point(7.35,8.20)
print p1.id
print p1
print p0 == p1
print p0.id == p1.id
```

I am not sure how to separate the x & y values in my Point class, for use in the equation.

Comment: You had no trouble doing exactly that in your `__str__` method...

Comment: Your `p1 = pts1` code is assigning the `pts1` variable before it's declared, which happens on the next line.

Comment: Why are you assigning to the parameter variables `p0` and `p1`?

Comment: Why does the `Point` class do its own `self.id` assignment, instead of just calling the parent class's `__init__` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `distance` method should operate on its own point (`self`, as you did in `__str__`) and the other point (might as well just call it `p`, or maybe something like `other`).

```
def distance(self, other):
    dist = math.sqrt((other.x - self.x) ** 2 + (other.y - self.y) ** 2)
    return dist
```

Example use:

```
p0 = Point(2, 4)
p1 = Point(6, 1)
print(str(p0.distance(p1)))
# 5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def distance(self, other):
    return math.sqrt((self.x - other.x)**2 + (self.y - other.y)**2)
```

You never defined the behavior for `some_point[index]` so it fails.  Access the variables the way you saved them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `p0.x`, `p0.y`, `p1.x`, `p1.y`. But you shouldn't overwrite the parameter variables.

```
def distance(p0, p1):
    dist = math.sqrt((p0.x - p1.x)**2 + (p0.y - p1.y)**2)
    return dist
```

Comment: Is this a module-level function taking two points, or is this a method taking one point (and using `p0` as a synonym for `p1`)?  Or is it just missing the `@staticmethod`?

Comment: It's a class method, `p0` is the object the method is called on. It's only a convention to call it `self`.

Comment: I'm probably violating a PEP8 rule, I suppose. I just copied that from the OP's code.

Comment: I was initially going to ignore it as just a PEP-8 nit-pick.  Then I thought you were missing the `@staticmethod`.  Then I figured you'd moved it to the module level and made it a function.  Then I realized I was just guessing, and stopped to ask directions.  (For the record, I took the OP's use of `p0` as a sign that he or she was confused about how the first parameter to a method works.  That's why I changed it to `self` in my answer --- to make it look more like the `__str__` method that seemed to be understood.)

Comment: I admit that I didn't really think about it much at all. I was just addressing the OP's problem with accessing the `x` and `y` properties.